# Remove Space Between div tags

Tags: css, html, xhtml-1.0-strict

I've read countless threads here now and I have been having no luck so far. I am trying to remove space between the divs on this page.

The divs called "postarea" and "rightsidebar" should have the same distance between "postadvert" as "postadvert" has on it's top between it and the menu. Can anyone help?

[image]

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steveyk/ePySF/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<title>DTR html</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="pageWrapper">

    <div class="header">

    <a href="images/banner_gundam_space.jpg"><img src="images/banner_gundam_space.jpg" width="600" height="150" alt="Banner" class="banner"/></a>

    <div id="rssline">
      <a href="localhost/dubtopian-review/register/"><img src="images/register.gif" width="70" height="40" alt="Register" class="rssline"/></a>

      <a href="#"><img src="images/commentsrss.gif" width="160" height="40" alt="CommentsRSS" class="rssline"/></a>

      <a href="#"><img src="images/entriesrss.gif" width="137" height="40" alt="EntriesRSS" class="rssline"/></a>
      </div>

    <div id="topadvert">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/adunit_234x60.gif" width="234" height="60" alt="Advert" /></a>
      </div>
    <div id="welcome"><img src="images/welcome.jpg" width="250" height="60" alt="Welcome to Dubtopia" /></div>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
            <li><a href="localhost/dubtopian-review/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="localhost/dubtopian-review/anime-reviews/">Anime Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="localhost/dubtopian-review/activity/">Activity</a></li>
            <li><a href="localhost/dubtopian-review/forums/">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="localhost/dubtopian-review/group-forums/">Group Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="localhost/dubtopian-review/groups/">Groups</a></li>
            <li><a href="localhost/dubtopian-review/members/">Members</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>

    </div><!-- End header -->

<div id="contentWrapper">

    <div id="postadvert"><img src="images/advert_example_728x90.png" width="729" height="90" alt="Advert" /></div>

    <div id="rightsidebar">

        <div class="rightcontainer">

            <div id="searchBox"><input type="text" name="search" size="25" /><input type="submit" value="Search" /></div>

            <div class="sidebaradvert"><img src="images/advert_example_300x250.png" width="300" height="250" alt="Advert" /></div>

            <div class="sidebarTitle1"><img src="images/recentseries.jpg" width="200" height="40" alt="Recent Series" /></div>
                <ol>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood</a></li>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">Aquarion Age</a></li>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">Gurren Lagann</a></li>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">Black Lagoon</a></li>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">Chrome Shelled Regios</a></li>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">Ergo Proxy</a></li>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">Ghost Hunt</a></li>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">Kurau Phantom Memory</a></li>
                    <li><a class="widgetlink" href="#">When They Cry</a></li>
                </ol>

        </div> <!-- END top series -->

    </div><!-- End rightsidebar -->

    <div id="postarea">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="postdate">5th Feb</div>
        <img src="images/anime_images/fullmetal_alchemist_brotherhood.jpg" width="225" height="329" alt="Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood" />
        <p class="postcontent"><h2><a class="postlink" href="#">Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood</a></h2><br />In this world there exist alchemists, people who study and perform the art of alchemical transmutation—to manipulate objects and transform one object into another. They are bounded by the basic law of alchemy: in order to gain something you have to sacrifice something of the same value. The main character is the famous alchemist Edward Elric—also known as the Fullmetal Alchemist—who almost lost his little brother, Alphonse, in an alchemical accident. Edward managed to attach his brother's soul to a large suit of armor. While he did manage to save his brother's life, he paid the terrible price of his limbs. To get back what they've lost, the brothers embark on a journey to find the Philosopher's Stone that is said to amplify the powers of an alchemist enormously. Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood is a re-telling of the story from the manga point of view.</p>
        <a class="postcomments" href="#">comments</a>
    </div><!-- End post -->

</div><!-- End postarea -->

<div id="footer">

    &copy; 2013 Dubtopian Review. "Dubtopian" - A fan of English dubbed anime.

</div><!-- End footer -->

</div><!-- End contentWrapper -->

</div><!-- End pageWrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS

```
    /* Typograhpy */

@charset "utf-8";
@font-face {
 font-family: Roboto;
 src: url('./webfonts/Roboto/Roboto-Black.eot'); /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
 font-family: Roboto;
 src: url('Roboto-Black.ttf') /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}

/* Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 - http://cssreset.com */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}

body {
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #666666;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.pageWrapper {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 1040px;
    background-color: #42413c;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h2 {
    font-size:16px;
    color:#E15122;
}

a {
    color:#FFF;
}

a:hover {
    color:#CCC;
}

/* Start of header */

.header {
    height: 211px;
    width: 1040px;
}

.banner {
    border:0px;
    position:relative;
}

.rssline {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 151px;
    left: 628px;
}

#rssline img {
    border:0px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px transparent;
}
#rssline img:hover {
    border-color: white;
}

#topadvert {
    border: 0px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 140px;
    left: 703px;
}

#welcome {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 113px;
}

#menu {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 177px;
    right: 10px;
}

.header #menu {
    float: right;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline;
}
.header #menu ul {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size:14px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:18px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
}
.header #menu li {
    display:inline;
}
.header #menu li a:link,a:visited {
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color:#2c2c2c;
    text-align:center;
    padding:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.header #menu li a:hover,a:active {
    background-color:#191919;
}

/* END header */

/* START slider area */

#slider {
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    width: 1020px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
}

/* END slider area */

/* START posts and sidebar */

#contentWrapper {
    width: 1040px;
    height: 100%;
}

#postadvert {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#postadvert img{
    position: relative;
    left: 140px;
}

/* START sidebar */

#searchBox {
    width:350px;
    height:40px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

.rightcontainer #searchBox input {
    position:relative;
    left:50px;
    top:6px;
}

#rightsidebar {
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#rightsidebar .rightcontainer .sidebarTitle1 img{
    position:relative;
    left:74px;
}

.number, .widgetlink {
    display:inline;
    margin-top:1px;
}



.rightcontainer ol {
    position:relative;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin:0px;
}

.rightcontainer ol li {
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.commentdate {
    background-color: #E15122;
    width:50px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.sidebaradvert {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color:#1f1f1f;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.sidebaradvert img {
    position:relative;
    left: 15px;
}

/* END sidebar */

/* START post area */

#postarea {
    Float:left;
    width: 620px;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.post {
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: justify;
    clear: both;
}

.postdate {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #E15122;
    width:50px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#postarea img {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}

#postarea h2, #postarea p {
    padding: 5px;   
}

#postarea h2 a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#E15122;
}

#postarea .post .postcomments {
    position:relative;
    left:500px;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* END post area */

/* START footer */

#footer {
    float: left;
    width: 1010px;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

/* END footer */
```

Answer (score 0):

Float the other elements too, besides postarea and rightsidebar.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ePySF/5/

```
.header #postadvert #contentwrapper {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the page now looks wrong. I wanted to keep all areas separated like this page http://jsfiddle.net/steveyk/LYLt4/

Comment: I found the problem. After narrowing it down, it all came to unwanted space created by floats. And that's when I came to this page 

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Clearing_Space

specifically this statement "Also remember that a float always contains children float, so often the simplest solution is just to float the container!"

I floated the contentWrapper to the left and the space moved from underneath the postadvert to above it, then I floated the header to the left and BAM everything displayed the way I wanted it to. This problem is now fixed.